# Blazor component OnAfterRender method happens only if there's Console.WriteLine called. Why?

Tags: blazor-webassembly

I'm new to Blazor and feel totally confuzed.

I'm using WASM Blazor.
My code should show loading spinner until page would load. And it works totally fine until I remove `Console.WriteLine("loaded!");` from `OnAfterRender` method. In this case loader class will never be updated from `page-loading active` to `page-loading`.

So the main question: what the reason of such weird behaviour?

The code itself:

`.razor`

```
<!-- Page loading spinner -->
<div class=@LoadingClass>
    <div class="page-loading-inner">
        <div class="page-spinner"></div><span>Loading...</span>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Page with long rendering -->
<SomeBlazorComponent />

@code {
  string LoadingClass { get; set; } = "page-loading active";

  protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender) {
    Console.WriteLine("loaded!");
    if (firstRender)
      LoadingClass = "page-loading";
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could try to add your could here together with your css https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet that way we can check it out

Comment: Thank you for reply. It seems, it does not work in mudblazor: https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/wkGnvamSnzOJVCCf

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this code:

```
  protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender) {
    Console.WriteLine("loaded!");
    if (firstRender)
      LoadingClass = "page-loading";
  }
```

to this:

```
  protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender) {
    if (firstRender)
    {
      LoadingClass = "page-loading";
      StateHasChanged();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.Class is being updated indeed, but it happens earlier than component's styles are being loaded. I suppose it's different issue.